# Method myLooper in android.os.Looper not mocked with Coroutines

Tags: android, junit, kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

I want to do some test of coroutines in JUnit but I met some problems. Code is easy:

```
@Test
fun coroutineTest() {
    //runBlocking(Unconfined) doesnt work too 
    runBlocking () {
        delay(1000)
        println("test")
    }
}
```

But I got that error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Method myLooper in android.os.Looper not mocked. See http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked for details.

at android.os.Looper.myLooper(Looper.java)
at kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.android.MainLooperChecker.checkRunBlocking(HandlerContext.kt:124)
at kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:42)
at kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source)
at app.deadmc.sometests.tests.ExampleUnitTest.coroutineTest(ExampleUnitTest.kt:22)
```

The first thing I thought about was wrong coroutine context. So to be sure I used `Unconfined` but that doesnt work.

I`ve tried

```
android {
  // ...
  testOptions { 
    unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
  }
}
```

But that doesn`t work too and I get following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: runBlocking is not allowed in Android main looper thread
```

But there is no `Android main looper` at all!

How can I run blocking coroutine in JUnit?

Comment: Kotlin recently added the check that you don't use `runBlocking` on the UI thread. But the check isn't appropriate in a unit test.

Comment: Related issue: "Support runBlocking for UI Tests" https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/464

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks [Marko Topolnik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1103872/marko-topolnik) for idea.

The problem is with [0.24.0 version of coroutines](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/releases/tag/0.24.0) because of:

> Attempts to use runBlocking from any supported UI thread (Android,
>   JavaFx, Swing) will result in exception.

Unfortunately release has a bug with `JUnit` tests, so it doesnt let to use `runBlocking` in JUnit aswell.

Solution is changing version of coroutines to `0.23.4`

Comment: In version 0.25.0 this change was reverted, see https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/releases/tag/0.25.0

Answer (score 0):

You can remove this check via an environment variable.

Either set it in your tests initilization:

```
System.setProperty("kotlinx.coroutines.blocking.checker", "disable")
```

Either set the env variable via Gradle with:

```
-Dkotlinx.coroutines.blocking.checker=disable
```